# Scroll to specific area on page load AND perform Ajax Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Good day folks. I need to figure out how to perform an action using Ajax once I have linked to a specific section on a page. I already know how to get to the designated DOM element on the other page, but I would like to go further as to perform some action using ajax once it has taken the visitor to that point.

eg.

```
<nav>
 <ul><li><a href="about.php#team"></a></li></ul>
</nav>
```

Will take me to this about.php page to the "team" div

```
<div>
 <div><a name="team"></a></div>
</div>
```

But then I would like to run some Ajax automatically that would usually be executed when the user clicks on some object in the "team" div. So should the user get to this section by way of the link up above, it will take them straight to the content. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `scrollTo()` to scroll to the area on the page, then use the `complete` function to call you ajax after the scroll has finished. 
Detailed Description [here](http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

```
$('body').scrollTo('#target', function()
{
    // Do your AJAX Thaaang
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually did the trick with a bit of tweaking. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad to hear it, No problem! :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you're using jQuery's `animate()` for the scrolling:

```
$('html, body').animate(
    { scrollTop: $("#something").offset().top },
    1000,
    function() {
        someAjaxFunction();
    }
);

var someAjaxFunction = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/something/'
    }).done(function(data) {
        // Done!
    });
};
```

We're using the callback function argument given to [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to fire off our ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

This check can be run to determine if the user has navigated directly to the teamDiv. Running it on page load would allow you to catch it in the event that the user was deep linked to the teamDiv from another page:

```
if (/#team/.test(window.location.href)) { // perform Ajax query here... }
```

Note: In the example link, you use the id `team` whereas the div's ID attribute is set to `teamDiv`. They need to be the same for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

So the code would run if the user clicks some object in the "team" div?

In that case, is this an option?

```
<div>
  <div id="teamDiv"><a name="team"></a>some element</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
       $("#teamDiv").click(function() {
            //put what you want to happen when the user clicks something in
            //teamDiv here
        });
 })
 </script>
```

Comment: he told this can be done usually by clicking but he want to do it automatically when the user scrolls to that particular div.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to read the current loaded url:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var location = window.location.href;
  if(location.indexOf('#team' > -1) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can check `location.hash` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) to determine if hash existed.
- If you want to do something in each variants of navigation to this div: click and scroll you can use something like this:

  `$(document).bind('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > $('.your-div').top()) {
      alert('do something');
    }
  })`